# Filter depending combobox with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, combobox, filter

How can i filter the second combobox choices based on what i select on first combobox?
So here is the controller... and the view file.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <section class="mainbar">
        <section class="matter">
            <div class="container">
                <h2></h2>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="widget wblue">
                        <div class="widget-content user">

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-foot">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <select ng-model="pSelected" ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in tier"></select>

                    <select ng-model="cSelected"
                            ng-options="c.name for c in cd"></select>

                    <label><input type="checkbox" </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
    </body>
```

and a simple JS

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).
    controller('myCtrl', function myCtrl($scope){


            $scope.tier = [
                { id: 1, name: 'Tier1Head' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Tier2Head' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Tier3Head' }
            ];

            $scope.cd = [
                { id: 1, idP: 1, name: 'Tier1' },
                { id: 2, idP: 1, name: 'Tier1' },
                { id: 3, idP: 1, name: 'Tier1' },
                { id: 4, idP: 2, name: 'Tier2' },
                { id: 5, idP: 2, name: 'Tier2' },
                { id: 6, idP: 3, name: 'Tier3' },
                { id: 7, idP: 3, name: 'Tier3' }
            ];
    })
```

And when i click the checkbox.. i need first combobox to be disabled(so i can't select other Parinte)

Comment: Please do not edit your example code out of your question. That seriously reduces its value to other users.

Comment: its same as begining. only data protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter results with pipe to filter
and use `ng-disabled` for select (i had a plnkr for you but it there is something wrong with plnkr functionality at this moment
so here is a HTML, i've change models for selects as well as extended their functionality

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<section class="mainbar">
    <section class="matter">
        <div class="container">
            <h2></h2>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="widget wblue">
                    <div class="widget-content user">

                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-foot">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>

                <select ng-model="pSelected" ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in tier"
                        ng-disabled="tierdisable"></select>

                <select ng-model="cSelected"
                        ng-options="c.name for c in cd | filter:{idP:pSelected}:true "></select>

                <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="tierdisable">Disable</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
</body>
```

and a simple JS

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('myCtrl', function myCtrl($scope){


        $scope.tier = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Tier1Head' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Tier2Head' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Tier3Head' }
        ];

        $scope.cd = [
            { id: 1, idP: 1, name: 'Tier1' },
            { id: 2, idP: 1, name: 'Tier1' },
            { id: 3, idP: 1, name: 'Tier1' },
            { id: 4, idP: 2, name: 'Tier2' },
            { id: 5, idP: 2, name: 'Tier2' },
            { id: 6, idP: 3, name: 'Tier3' },
            { id: 7, idP: 3, name: 'Tier3' }
        ];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

disabled :

```
<div>
                Parinti: 
                <select ng-model="vm.parinti" ng-options="parinte.nume for parinte in vm.parinti" ng-disabled="checked"></select>
                Copii: 
                <select ng-model="vm.copii" ng-options="copil.nume for copil in vm.copii "></select>
                Blocat:
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">

            </div>
```

Comment: well..i need to filter the second combobox by  idParinte from copii = id from parinti. and..how can i add reputation to you and maurycy?

Comment: I've implemented filter by idParinte for you in my response

for a reputation you can either accept one of answers as correct and then upvote the other une with arrow up (left side next to answer)